# Django from query to dict of dict

Tags: django, dictionary

I have 3 models:

```
class LawTt(models.Model):
    tt = models.CharField()
    txt = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', blank=True, null=True)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(LawRank)

    def get_law(self):
        return Law.objects.filter(law_tt=self)

class Law(models.Model):
    tt = models.CharField()
    txt = models.TextField()
    law_tt = models.ForeignKey(LawTt)

    def get_item(self):
        return LawItm.objects.filter(law=self)

class LawItm(models.Model):
    law = models.ForeignKey(Law)
    txt = models.TextField()
```

views.py:

```
class ViewLaw(ListView):
    model=Law
    context_object_name = 'law'
    ...
```

My experience allows this:

```
{% if law.all.0.law_tt.parent.parent %}
    {{law.all.0.law_tt.parent.parent.rank}}
{%endif%}
{% if law.all.0.law_tt.parent %}
    {{law.all.0.law_tt.parent.rank}}
{%endif%}
{% if law.all.0.law_tt %}
    {{law.all.0.law_tt.rank}}
{% endif %}
{% for n in law %}
    {{n.txt|safe}}
        {% for i in n.get_item %}
            {{i.txt|safe}}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But this experience for too many SQL-queries. It`s bad.
I what get less queries. So that, i think need dictionary, for my solution. I need this:

```
[{
    'title_one': 'bla_one1', 
        'two': [
        {'title_two': 'bla_two1',},
        {'title_two': 'bla_two2',},
        {'title_two': 'bla_two3',},
    ],
    'title_one': 'bla_one2', 
        'two': [
        {'title_two': 'bla_two4',},
        {'title_two': 'bla_two5',},
        {'title_two': 'bla_two6',},
    ]
}]
```

Help me understand this

**Update**

```
LawTt model: name law or section or paragraph
LawRank: simple drop-down list (paragraph, section...)
Law: article law
LawItm: item law
```

I want more than my question. It may be possible to make with one query:

```
Name Law
    Section 1. name section 1
        Paragraph 1. name paragraph 1
            Article 1. name article 1
                Item 1: name item 1
                Item 2: name item 2
                Item 3: name item 3
                ...
            Article 2. name article 2
                Item 1: name item 1
                ...
        Paragraph 2. name paragraph 2
            Article 3. name article 3
                Item 1: name item 1
                ...
                Item 2: name item 2
            Article 4. name article 4
    Section 2. name section 2
        ...may be have not paragraph (or and section)
        Article 5. name article 5
            Item 1: name item 1
        Article 6. name article 6
            ...
```

Comment: You have two more models? `LawTt` and `LawRank`. Are they relevant here? Can you tell us what you want to achieve in the view?